# Python throws a syntax error for else: statement

Tags: python, if-statement, syntax-error

```
def ask():
    while True:
        try:
            num = int(input("Enter an integer:"))
        except:  
            print('Not a number, please try again')
        continue
        else:
            print('Thats a valid number!')
            break
        finally:
            print('All done')
```

I get this error-I checked and rechecked indentaion, but still not working

```
File "<ipython-input-46-ff8c841c59c4>", line 8
    else:
       ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Comment: Check the indentation again. `else` is invalid following `continue`.

Comment: BTW welcome to SO! Check out the [tour]. In the future, you need to provide a [mre]. In this case, the function and loop are irrelevant to the problem, so it would help to remove it, to make the problem more obvious to you and us. Also BTW, a [bare `except` is bad practice](https://stackoverflow.com/q/54948548/4518341). use the specific exception you're expecting, `ValueError`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

your else statement is not needed here :) try this:

```
def ask(): 
    while True: 
        try: 
            num = int(input("Enter an integer:")) 
            print('Thats a valid number!') 
            break 
        except:
            print('Not a number, please try again') 
            continue 
        finally: 
            print('All done')
```

Comment: It's not necessary, but it is better practice because you should put as little as possible in a `try` statement. Also, this doesn't address what caused the syntax error.

Answer (score 0):

Your syntax is wrong

```
def ask(): 
    while True: 
        try: 
            num = int(input("Enter an integer:")) 
        except ValueError:
            print('Not a number, please try again') 
            continue 
        except: 
            print('Thats a valid number!') 
            break 
        finally: 
            print('All done')
```

Comment: It would help to explain *how* it's wrong, and what you fixed. I notice you also added `except ValueError`, and that definitely needs an explanation cause it's not part of the problem. You can use this snippet if you'd like: ``a [bare `except` is bad practice](https://stackoverflow.com/q/54948548/4518341). use the specific exception you're expecting, `ValueError`.``